# multiple echo statements in one echo?

Tags: php, html

I am relatively new to PHP and want to know a more efficient way of echo'ing the following in less steps or even just one statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$result = OpenCon()->query($sql); 
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='card'><p class: card-text>";
    echo $row['uid']."<br>";
    echo $row['date']."<br>";
    echo $row['message']."<br><br>";
    echo "</p></div>";
```

Comment: You could use the "." separator to concatenate the different variables and quoted strings onto a single line of code, or use `printf()` which takes a format string and multiple variables. Whether either would be easier to read or modify is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Do you mean "more efficient" for the computer? Answer: don't worry about such tiny details. Do you mean "more efficient" for the code? Answer: that's a matter of opinion. Do you mean "more efficient" in terms of just "fewer characters"? Answer: see [all the ways you can specify strings in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @droopsnoot has commented on above, you should try doing the next thing here.

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='card'><p class: card-text>". $row['uid']."<br>" . $row['date']."<br>".$row['message']."<br><br>". "</p></div>";
 }
```

It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to close php tag (`?>`) and use html markup with `<?=$var?>`:

```php
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$result = OpenCon()->query($sql); 
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
    <div class="card">
        <p class="card-text">
            <?=$row['uid']?><br>
            <?=$row['date']?><br>
            <?=$row['message']?><br><br>
       </p>
    </div>
<?php
}  // end while
```